# Take picture only with android camera intent in Kotlin, not video

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

I am using the following Kotlin code to open the camera on a simple Android App and take a user profile picture.  I want to only take pictures, NOT video.  When I start the activity and the camera opens it also lets me record video.

```
val contentVvalues = ContentValues()
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg")
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "My Picture")
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "My first picture")
this.imageURI = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)

val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageURI)

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE)
```

I was wondering in anyone could help me with how I could go about having the image controls only?

I also notice I get the stickers and other controls.  How do I remove those?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I start the activity and the camera opens it also lets me record video.

There are ~2.5 billion Android devices, spread across ~26,000 device models. There will be dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed camera apps across those device models that might respond to `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. There are also dozens, if not hundreds, of camera apps that the user might have installed that might respond to `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Your code could be starting any of those hundreds of apps.

And what a camera app does is up to the developers of the camera app, not you.

> I also notice I get the stickers and other controls. How do I remove those?

You don't. That is the choice of the camera app developers.

In the case of offering both still image and video capture, that's arguably a bug in that particular camera app. There is very little that you can do about that.

> I was wondering in anyone could help me with how I could go about having the image controls only?

Stop using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Write your own camera code, probably using a library (Google's CameraX, Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android, etc.).

Comment: Ahhh, I. get it.  Fairly new too Android so I did not understand that.  Thank you for the reply.  I will look into Camera or CamerKit.

Comment: @LilMoke: CameraX *probably* will be the winner in this space long term, as it is from Google. However, it is still in an `alpha` release, whereas the others have been around for years.